# Floating point exception and coredump using Virtual TMB

Tags: c++, linux, rcpp, tmb

I'm facing NA/NaN errors with my TMB code. Searching on the internet, I found that including `fenv.h` file into my code can give me a clue about the source of errors.

Since this example [nan error](https://kaskr.github.io/adcomp/_book/Errors.html) does not work on Windows, I decided to follow an advice to run this example in Virtual TMB (Because my old desktop cannot afford to run more than one operating system).

But the new problem appeared. I get `unused variable errors` after running the code.
This code is copied and pasted from the link above.

***cpp code***

```
// Illustrates how to make the debugger catch a floating point error.
#include <TMB.hpp>
#include <fenv.h> // Extra line needed

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
  feenableexcept(FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW | FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_UNDERFLOW); // Extra line needed

  DATA_SCALAR(lambda);
  PARAMETER(x);
  Type f;
  f = sqrt(-1.);        // FE_INVALID   ( sqrt(-1.) returns NaN )
  //f = 1./0.;          // FE_DIVBYZERO ( division by zero )
  //f = exp(100000.);   // FE_OVERFLOW  ( exp(100000.) returns Inf )   [Does not work on all platforms]
  //f = exp(-100000.);  // FE_UNDERFLOW ( exp(-100000.) returns 0 )
  return f;
}
```

***and here is the corresponding r code for Linux***

```
data <- list(lambda = 25)
parameters <- list(x=1)
require(TMB)
compile('nan.cpp','-fno-gnu-unique -O0 -Wall')
dyn.load(dynlib('nan'))

model <- MakeADFun(data, parameters)
fit <- nlminb(model$par, model$fn, model$gr)
rep <- sdreport(model)

print(rep)
```

I attached my sessionInfo and the warning messages via image files.

***Error***

```
nan.cpp: In instantiation of 'Type objective_function<Type>::operator()() [with Type =double]':
/home/tmb/r/library/TMB/include/tmb_core.hpp:1416:16:   required from here
nan.cpp:7:15:warning:unused variable 'lambda' [-Wunused -variable]
DATA_SCALAR(lambda);
            ^
/home/tmb/r/library/TMB/include/tmb_core.hpp:199:32: note: in definition of macro 'DATA_SCALAR'
#define DATA_SCALAR(name) Type name(asVector<Type>( \
nan.cpp:8:13: warning: unused variable 'x' [-Wunused-variable]
PARAMETER(x);
          ^
/home/tmb/r/library/TMB/include/tmb_core.hpp:182:30: note: in definition of macro 'PARAMETER'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

---

***Warning message***:

[image: warning message]

---

***Session Info***:

[image: sessionInfo]

Comment: I think you are doing this wrong. When you say `I'm recently facing NA/NaN error with my TMB code.` I would suggest to debug your code and learning what leads to the `NA` / `NaN` output.

Comment: Please state the warnings and errors. The text on the picture cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Dear @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for your comment! 
What I really trying to figure out is NA/NaN source from my code (it is not posted here) with the header file <fenv.h> and the function feenableexcept(). I tried on Window by including fenv.h and the function in my code, but it did not work and an error pops up ''feenableexcept' was not declared in this scope'. On Linux, only an error message with 'unused variable errors' comes up.

Comment: Dear @jww Thank you I'll edit my post.

Comment: The "unused variable" message is a warning, not an error, and it is not preventing your code from compiling or running.  It looks like it ran and produced a floating point exception - is that not what you expected?

Comment: @Ellie you may have misunderstood what I was trying to say. In essence, forget `fenv.h` especially if you problem with it. Rather do old-school debugging, maybe with print statements, to see where/how your calculations go sour.

Comment: Moreover, I just tried the `fenv.h` example in Rcpp code alone without TMB and it did not work--still segfaults.

Comment: Dear @aschepler Thank you for your comment! You're right. I expected the error message with line numbers. I did not read the messages carefully. But still, why the warning message comes up after running the code{unused variable}

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you again. I just printed my code with large font size!
In case of your trial, did you run it on Windows?